# using jquery submit ($.submit) how to modify the form values before submit?

Tags: jquery, forms, http-post, form-submit

In my form I want to remove some special characters like space, if entered by user, before I submit the form. I clearly did this by following way .

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function()
{
        var modifiedval=$(this).val().replace(//regexpr to remove the specialchar);
        $("#"+$(this).attr("id")).val(modifiedval);
 });
 $("form#myform").submit();
```

Only issue is, when the form submit, doing some actions in the backend. It takes some times to post. So when remove the special characters the user got idea the special characters are removed.

I want to hide this action. So I did the `$.post` method to post the form after modify the serialize data. It also works good.

But the URL doesn't goes to the action page. Because it did in ajax. But I want to go the action page along with the modified data like submit. Is it possible in jQuery with modified data submit.

1) My point to achieve - the user must not see the modified value before form submit but needs to post the modified data to backend.

Note: I can't change the action page which was already developed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you try to remove the characters on backend rather than doing it on client side so the users can't see it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the success callback function of your AJAX call.

```
$.post('POST_URL', 'MODIFIED_DATA', function(data) { 
    window.location = 'YOUR_NEW_LOCATION';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just catch the click event that is made to submitButton and then get values in the form and make your controls and then make an ajax request to your server and of course do not forget to stop action of the submit button. You can do your action inside of this code block;

```
$("#submitButtom").on('click',function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();    //Prevents the default action of the button

    //Your controls
    //Your ajax request with the variables you want
    //You can redirect user to different pages on ajax's success return part
    //Or you can clear inside of your input boxes
}
```